# How can i combine, two OnClickListener in ArrayAdapter (View) on Android

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

I have two OnClickListeners in my ArrayAdapter under View.

I have onClick row and onClick button, both are in the same Listview. I would like to combine them. Make one OnClickListener for both. They both go to the same Intent/page when clicked.

Not sure how to do this, without duplicating my code.

Thanks in advance.

```
  public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private List<ExerciseListModel> exModelList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ExerciseListModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        exModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            holder.exTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
            holder.exBody = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myBody);
            holder.exId = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myId);
            holder.exDone = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myCount);
            holder.exIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myIcon);
            holder.btnStart = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //onClick Row
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final View v) {

                String nid = exModelList.get(position).getNid();
                String title = exModelList.get(position).getTitle();
                String body = exModelList.get(position).getBody();

                Intent intent = new Intent(ExerciseListActivity.this, ExerciseDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("nid", nid);
                intent.putExtra("title", title);
                intent.putExtra("body", body);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //onClick Button
        holder.btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final View v) {

                String nid = exModelList.get(position).getNid();
                String title = exModelList.get(position).getTitle();
                String body = exModelList.get(position).getBody();

                Intent intent = new Intent(ExerciseListActivity.this, ExerciseDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("nid", nid);
                intent.putExtra("title", title);
                intent.putExtra("body", body);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.exId.setText("ID: " + exModelList.get(position).getNid());
        holder.exBody.setText(exModelList.get(position).getBody());
        holder.exTitle.setText(exModelList.get(position).getTitle());

        if(exModelList.get(position).getExercise_done().equals("[]")){
            holder.exDone.setText(exercise_not_done);
            holder.exIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.exercise_not_started);
        }else{
            String exercise_count = exModelList.get(position).getExercise_done();
            String ex_done = exercise_done + " " + exercise_count + " " + exercise_times_done;
            holder.exDone.setText(ex_done);
            holder.exIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.exercise_started);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    class ViewHolder{
        private TextView exTitle;
        private TextView exBody;
        private TextView exId;
        private ImageView exIcon;
        private TextView exDone;
        private Button btnStart;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your activity/Fragment (where you declare the ListView)

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(ExerciseListActivity.this, ExerciseDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("nid", nid);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            intent.putExtra("body", body);
            startActivity(intent);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This code may help you,defining OnClicklistener method to both View
>   and Button.

```
    public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

        private List<ExerciseListModel> exModelList;
        private int resource;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ExerciseListModel> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            exModelList = objects;
            this.resource = resource;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if(convertView == null){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
                holder.exTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
                holder.exBody = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myBody);
                holder.exId = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myId);
                holder.exDone = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myCount);
                holder.exIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myIcon);
                holder.btnStart = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            //onClick Row
            convertView(OnClickListener);

            //onClick Button
            holder.btnStart(OnClickListener)
            holder.exId.setText("ID: " + exModelList.get(position).getNid());
            holder.exBody.setText(exModelList.get(position).getBody());
            holder.exTitle.setText(exModelList.get(position).getTitle());

            if(exModelList.get(position).getExercise_done().equals("[]")){
                holder.exDone.setText(exercise_not_done);
                holder.exIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.exercise_not_started);
            }else{
                String exercise_count = exModelList.get(position).getExercise_done();
                String ex_done = exercise_done + " " + exercise_count + " " + exercise_times_done;
                holder.exDone.setText(ex_done);
                holder.exIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.exercise_started);
            }
            return convertView;
        }
public void OnClickListener() {                

                    String nid = exModelList.get(position).getNid();
                    String title = exModelList.get(position).getTitle();
                    String body = exModelList.get(position).getBody();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(ExerciseListActivity.this, ExerciseDetailsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("nid", nid);
                    intent.putExtra("title", title);
                    intent.putExtra("body", body);
                    startActivity(intent);

            }
        class ViewHolder{
            private TextView exTitle;
            private TextView exBody;
            private TextView exId;
            private ImageView exIcon;
            private TextView exDone;
            private Button btnStart;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If both onClickListeners have the same functionality then you don't need to add onClickListener to the button as well. Simply remove this listener and only add it to your row. It will work even when you click on the button.
Simply do something like this

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private List<ExerciseListModel> exModelList;
private int resource;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ExerciseListModel> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    exModelList = objects;
    this.resource = resource;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if(convertView == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
        holder.exTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
        holder.exBody = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myBody);
        holder.exId = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myId);
        holder.exDone = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myCount);
        holder.exIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myIcon);
        holder.btnStart = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //onClick Row
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View v) {

            String nid = exModelList.get(position).getNid();
            String title = exModelList.get(position).getTitle();
            String body = exModelList.get(position).getBody();

            Intent intent = new Intent(ExerciseListActivity.this, ExerciseDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("nid", nid);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            intent.putExtra("body", body);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    holder.exId.setText("ID: " + exModelList.get(position).getNid());
    holder.exBody.setText(exModelList.get(position).getBody());
    holder.exTitle.setText(exModelList.get(position).getTitle());

    if(exModelList.get(position).getExercise_done().equals("[]")){
        holder.exDone.setText(exercise_not_done);
        holder.exIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.exercise_not_started);
    }else{
        String exercise_count = exModelList.get(position).getExercise_done();
        String ex_done = exercise_done + " " + exercise_count + " " + exercise_times_done;
        holder.exDone.setText(ex_done);
        holder.exIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.exercise_started);
    }
    return convertView;
}
class ViewHolder{
    private TextView exTitle;
    private TextView exBody;
    private TextView exId;
    private ImageView exIcon;
    private TextView exDone;
    private Button btnStart;
}
```

}

EDIT: Or you can follow @GiuseppeLabanca's code and remove both onClickListeners from the adapter.